# Eclipse RCP - ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor - setShellStyle(SWT.MIN) not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

We have developed an eclipse rcp application using 3.5 and are trying to move it to 4.2.1.

It is a simple RCP application with a view. On doing the basics and launching it I found that the setShellStyle(SWT.MIN) is not working anymore. Since it was a single view application, it didnt require re-sizing, hence we had disabled re-sizing using this API.

But with the new Eclipse (Eclipse 4.2.1), the re-size/maximize button is enabled even when this method is called. I have verified that other APIs called from here work (other than this I used setShowStatusLine(false) and setShowCoolBar(false).

Is this a known problem with Eclipse 4 or whether there is a different API to get this functionality working with this.

I appreciate any kind of help I can get here.?

Comment: is this issue also related to  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331402 by any chance. I see discussions by Tomasz Galazka about a non-re-size-able view which is what even I want. Any suggestions here please?

Comment: Hi Paul, I just found that there is a defect raised in bugzilla against 4.2 for the problem mentioned in my question. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379396. Can you please check and let us know on the way forward for these cases?